# How to determine if a UIView has a delegate that conforms to a protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols, hittest

I have written a custom class that depends significantly on touch dragging/positioning, outside of it's own view boundaries.
There is an associated protocol defined with various relevant methods.
An example of something that would use this protocol would be a view that allows things to be dropped into it from my custom class.

The problem I have is in figuring out when a touch is ended (the object is 'dropped'), whether or not there is an object that cares below that position. (For 'cares', read 'conforms to the protocol'!).

If it's a view that conforms to my protocol, it's easy, I can find it with `- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint` or something along those lines and query with a `conformsToProtocol:@protocol(xx)`.

But if it is a view which is a subview of a UIViewController (for example), the *view* does not conform to the protocol, even though the UIViewController (as it's delegate) does.
If the view really does want to be notified, I need to be able to figure out who it's delegate is, to message.

So, essentially, how do I traverse up the view hierarchy from the lowest UIView, asking if each view conforms to my protocol; and if it doesn't, does it have a delegate, and does that conform..?

Or is there a much easier way I haven't thought of?

Thanks very much..

---

#### Solved

Thanks to [moshy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179383/moshy), I've got a solution:

```
- (UIView *)viewThatConformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol AtPointInWindow:(CGPoint)point {
   UIView *lowestUIView = [[(AppDelegate).navigationController view] hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
   UIResponder *respondsToProtocol = lowestUIView;
   while ((respondsToProtocol != nil) && (![respondsToProtocol conformsToProtocol:protocol])) {
      respondsToProtocol = [respondsToProtocol nextResponder]; // else try the next responder up the chain
   };
   return (UIView *)respondsToProtocol;
}
```

This either returns the view, or `nil` if nothing conforms.

Thanks again..

Comment: Be careful, if the only objects that implement the protocol are going to be UIViews then this will work fine, but if not then you might end up trying to cast a UIViewController to a UIView. You could make it so the method returns (id <Protocol>) instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once you have the lowest view, you could walk up the responder chain using `- (UIResponder *)nextResponder`.

From the docs:

> The UIResponder class does not store
>   or set the next responder
>   automatically, instead returning nil
>   by default. Subclasses must override
>   this method to set the next responder.
>   UIView implements this method by
>   returning the UIViewController object
>   that manages it (if it has one) or its
>   superview (if it doesn’t);
>   UIViewController implements the method
>   by returning its view’s superview;
>   UIWindow returns the application
>   object, and UIApplication returns nil.